# Print big number from double variable in a readable format in Java

Tags: java, numbers, double

I have a **double** value, which can have a big value. Therefore it will display a number containing an **E** character.
How can I get the original big value from that double?

Example:

```
double d = 420000382.34;
System.out.println(d);
```

output will be:

> 4.2000038234E8

But I want this output somehow:

> 420000382.34

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double d = 420000382.34;
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(d)+"");
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple way to print double in normal number without E notation

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

or you can use `printf`

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", d);
```

or you can do something as below

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", d));
```